# Forecast the remaining time of a loop

Tags: python, for-loop, forecasting

Good Evening,

I am trying to **estimate** the **remaining** **time** to the end of a loop; I've used:

```
start = datetime.now()
progress = 0

for i in range(1000): 

    #do a few calculations

    progress += 1

    stop = datetime.now()
    execution_time = stop-start 

    remaining = execution_time * ( 1000 - progress )

    print("Progress:", progress, "%, estimated", remaining, "time remaining")
```

But it does **not** seem to work properly, since it goes up to minutes, even though the loop would take 20 seconds in total, and decrease quickly when reaching the end.

How can I try to **forecast** the **remaining** **time** of a loop efficiently and correctly?

Comment: What is `execution_time_1`?

Comment: `time_by_loop = (execution_time_1.microseconds/progress)`

Comment: If time_by_loop is the time required for one step, then you want `remaining=time_by_loop * (1000-progress)`.

Comment: BTW, you should use [`time.perf_counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter) (or perhaps `time.process_time()`) rather than `datetime.datetime.now()` for this sort of thing. If necessary, you can use `time` or `datetime` functions to format the raw seconds as hours:minutes:seconds.

Comment: Possibly the [`tqdm`](https://pypi.org/project/tqdm/) package might provide what you need.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply use `tqdm` package:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
for i in tqdm(range(10000)):
    dosomthing()
```

It will print everything for you:

```
76%|█████████████           | 7568/10000 [00:33<00:10, 229.00it/s]
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using `datetime.datetime.now()` for this sort of thing you can use [`time.perf_counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter), which is available in Python 3.3+. From the docs:

> Return the value (in fractional seconds) of a performance counter,
>   i.e. a clock with the highest available resolution to measure a short
>   duration. It does include time elapsed during sleep and is
>   system-wide. The reference point of the returned value is undefined,
>   so that only the difference between the results of consecutive calls
>   is valid.

Also, you can print using a carriage return instead of a newline so that the progress reports are printed on a single line. Here's a brief demo derived from your code.

```
from time import sleep, perf_counter

fmt = "  Progress: {:>3}% estimated {:>3}s remaining"
num = 1000

start = perf_counter()
for i in range(1, num + 1):
    # Simulate doing a few calculations
    sleep(0.01)

    stop = perf_counter()
    remaining = round((stop - start) * (num / i - 1))
    print(fmt.format(100 * i // num, remaining), end='\r')
print()
```

Depending on your terminal (and Python version) you may also need to add the `flush=True` keyword arg to the `print` call in order to get the progress reports to print as they are issued.

Answer (score 0):

I think that in this line:

```
remaining = execution_time * ( 1000 - progress )
```

you should divide execution_time/progress, because you want to know how long it takes to complete one percent of progress.

```
remaining = execution_time/progress * ( 1000 - progress )
```

Answer (score -1):

Your calculation for time remaining is wrong. If it takes `execution_time` for `progress` steps. Then how much does it take for `1000` steps ?

Simple cross multiply gives you the total time. Subtract it from the time already elapsed and that will give you the time remaining.

```
remaining_time = execution_time * 1000 / progress - execution_time
percent_complete =  (progress  / 1000) * 100     #You can simplify this if you like
print("Progress:", percent_complete , "%, Estimated", remaining_time, "time remaining")
```

Also your variable `execution_time_1` is never defined